# How to pivot a pandas dataframe using a modified index?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, dataframe, pivot

I have a timeseries dataframe of the form:

```
rng = pd.date_range('1/1/2013', periods=1000, freq='10min')
ts = pd.Series(np.random.randn(len(rng)), index=rng)
ts = ts.to_frame(name=None)
```

I need to do two things to it:

**Step 1:** Modify the index, so that every day starts at 17:00:00 of the day before. I do this using:

```
ts.index = pd.to_datetime(ts.index.values + np.where((ts.index.time >= datetime.time(17)), pd.offsets.Day(1).nanos, 0))
```

**Step 2:** Pivot the dataframe, like this:

```
ts_ = pd.pivot_table(ts, index=ts.index.date, columns=ts.index.time, values=0)
```

The problem I have, is that when pivoting the dataframe, pandas seems to forget the modification of index I made in Step 1.

This is what I get

```
             00:00:00    00:10:00    00:20:00   ...  23:50:00
2013-01-10  -1.800381   -0.459226   -0.172929   ... -1.000381
2013-01-11  -1.258317   -0.973924    0.955224   ...  0.072929
2013-01-12  -0.834976    0.018793   -0.141608   ...  2.072929
2013-01-13  -0.131197    0.289998    2.200644   ...  1.589998
2013-01-14  -0.991653    0.276874   -1.390654   ... -2.090654
```

Instead this is the desired outcome

```
             17:00:00    17:10:00    17:20:00   ...  16:50:00
2013-01-10  -2.800381    1.000226    2.172929   ...  0.172929
2013-01-11   0.312587    1.003924    2.556624   ... -0.556624
2013-01-12   2.976834    1.000003   -2.141608   ... -1.141608
2013-01-13   1.197131    1.333998   -2.999944   ... -1.999944
2013-01-14  -1.653991    1.278884   -1.390654   ... -4.390654
```

**Edit - Clarification Note:** Please notice how Its desired that each day starts at '17:00:00' ends at '16:50:00'.

Using Python 2.7

**Note:** The solution presented by Nickil Maveli aproximates the answer but is shifting the date the wrong way. The idea is that Day_t = Starts at Day_t-1 at '17:00'. Right now, the solution is doing Day_t = Starts at Day_t at '17:00'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I needed to draw some pictures, so [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFQPa.jpg) they are:

```
# Step 1:

df1 = df.ix[:,         :'16:59'] # http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ix.html
df2 = df.ix[:, '17:00' :       ]

# Step 2:

df3 = df2.shift(periods = 1) # http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html

# Step 3: 

df4 = pandas.concat([df3, df1], axis = 1) # http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html
```

Answer (score 2):

You really do not need to use `np.where` here as you are merely performing filtering on just 1 parameter. Also, the `else` part is made 0. So, there is absolutely no reduction in the index obtained after this step.

Instead you must, do:

1.Build up a boolean mask to filter datetime whose `hour` attribute is greater than or equal to 17 with an offset of a day added:

```
arr = ts.index
idx = arr[arr.hour >= 17] + pd.offsets.Day(1)
```

2.Reindex based on the modified index:

```
ts_clip = ts.reindex(idx)
```

3.Perform `pivot` operation:

```
pd.pivot_table(ts_clip, index=ts_clip.index.date, columns=ts_clip.index.time, values=0)
```

[image]

---

***Edit***

```
ts_clip = ts.iloc[np.argwhere(ts.index.hour.__eq__(17)).ravel()[0]:]
ts_clip_shift = ts_clip.tshift(-17, freq='H')
df = pd.pivot_table(ts_clip_shift, index=(ts_clip_shift.index + pd.offsets.Day(n=1)), 
                    columns=ts_clip_shift.index.time, values=0)
df.columns= ts_clip.iloc[:len(df.columns)].index.time
```

Check `DF` characteristics:

```
df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 7 entries, 2013-01-02 to 2013-01-08
Columns: 144 entries, 17:00:00 to 16:50:00
dtypes: float64(144)
memory usage: 7.9+ KB
```

Comment: The solution you presented 'chops' the data, where each day goes to from '17:00' to '23:50". I need each day to go from '17:00' to '16;50'.

Comment: I discovered the issue. At some point the procedure is shifting the days the wrong way. The idea is that Day_t = Starts at Day_t-1 at '17:00'. Right now, the solution is doing Day_t = Starts at Day_t at '17:00'. I added a note.

Comment: (*See edit merged on older one*) You should be fine now. Idea is - Wait till 17:00 hours arrive for the first day. Only begin our shifted series from this index. However only change is, while performing pivot, simply provide an offset of 1 day to it's index argument keeping other values in all columns intact. This corresponds to (day - day @ new index) = 1 day (lag). So, our date which was initially at 2013/1/1 → 2013/1/7 now become 2013/1/2 → 2013/1/8 as seen in `info` output.