# How to replace df.ix with df.loc or df.iloc?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, deprecated

Given the [coming deprecation of df.ix[...]](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/whatsnew.html#whatsnew-0200-api-breaking-deprecate-ix)

How can i replace .ix in this piece of code?

```
df_1 = df.ix[:,        :datetime.time(16, 50)]
df_2 = df.ix[:, datetime.time(17, 0) :       ]
df_3 = df2.shift(periods = 1) 
df_4 = pd.concat([df3, df1], axis = 1)
```

For reference, [this is some background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40821819/how-to-pivot-a-pandas-dataframe-using-a-modified-index) on that piece of code

Comment: @MaxU let me know if the link is enough. If not I can improve the question with a more generic dummy df.

Comment: hmm, `df.loc[:, :datetime.time(1, 00)]` and `df.loc[:, datetime.time(22, 00):]` works just fine for me (Pandas 0.19.2)

Comment: @MaxU  Im using '0.18.1' ...

Comment: time to update ? ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replacing `ix` in your code base is a 4-step process as follows:

1. Spend developer time on upgrading the production version of pandas to 0.19.x that is compatible with `ix` and expose `loc` `iloc`replacements as you would use them now. The impact in your code is adapations for other parts of your pandas code base that will have breaking changes due to other changes in pandas 0.19 vs 0.18
2. Install you new qualified version in production
3. Migrate `ix` in your code base
4. Deploy in production